# Django filter many to many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have problem with manyToMany models in django. I have structure like this:

Table **Project**

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ordernr = models.IntegerField(db_column='orderNr', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    map = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through='ProjectMapImage')

    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'Project'
```

And table **Image**

```py
class Image(models.Model):
     url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
     typeid = models.ForeignKey('ImageType', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='typeId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     ordernr = models.IntegerField(db_column='orderNr', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'Image'
         ordering = ['ordernr']
```

Mapping table **ProjectMapImage**

```py
class ProjectMapImage(models.Model):
     projectid = models.ForeignKey(Project, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectId', blank=True,
                                   null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     imageid = models.ForeignKey(Image, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='imageId', blank=True,
                                 null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'Project_Map_Image'
```

Finally this is my view

```py
class ProjectListView(ListView):
     model = Project
     context_object_name = "projects"
```

This view return all project and i have access to all linked images in HTML `{% for image in project.map.all %}`

But I wanto to load only images with `typeid` for example **1**. How can I filter this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply add the targeted queryset you would like to use in the front end.

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model = Project
    context_object_name = "projects"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(imageid__typeid=1)
```

Or you can do a logical filter in the template to check the `typeid` before rendering by checking for the attribute in the template logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work in view. I got error:
**Cannot resolve keyword 'imageid' into field. Choices are: description, projectmapcategory, projectmapimage,  id, map, name, ordernr.**